# Can't print PDFs under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing, pdf

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.  If I try to print a PDF from the default viewer, it displays a message to say that printing completed successfully, but nothing comes out of the printer.  If I open the same PDF in the Chrome browser I can print it from there.  How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Edit #1:

```
erik@laptop:~$ lpstat -t 
scheduler is running 
system default destination: MG2400-series 
device for MG2400-series: usb://Canon/MG2400%20series?serial=B6083B&interface=1 
MG2400-series accepting requests since Sat 13 Oct 2018 12:45:08 AM CEST printer MG2400-series is idle. enabled since Sat 13 Oct 2018 12:45:08 AM CEST
```

Edit #2:

```
erik@laptop:~$ lpq
MG2400-series is ready
no entries

erik@laptop:~$ sudo cupsenable MG2400-series

erik@laptop:~$ journalctl $(type -p cupsd)
-- Logs begin at Sat 2018-09-01 20:40:57 CEST, end at Sun 2018-10-14 12:01:00 CE
-- No entries --
```

Comment: Do you have CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) set up and working? `service cups status` will tell you. Does CUPS know about your printer? `lpstat -t`

Comment: `erik@laptop:~$ lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: MG2400-series
device for MG2400-series: usb://Canon/MG2400%20series?serial=B6083B&interface=1
MG2400-series accepting requests since Sat 13 Oct 2018 12:45:08 AM CEST
printer MG2400-series is idle.  enabled since Sat 13 Oct 2018 12:45:08 AM CEST`

Comment: the fact that i can print the PDF just fine from Chrome, isn't that proof that the printer is working?  i can print from other apps too, just not the default PDF reader.

Comment: Generally, editing one's post, and adding the additional information there, rather than in comments, is preferred. I'll do it for you this time.

Comment: You're missing a line that I see in MY `lpstat -t`. Right after `printer xxx is idle`, I see "`ready to print`". Try `lpq`, `sudo cupsenable  MG2400-series`. Check the logs `journalctl $(type -p cupsd)`, check more logs in `/var/spool/cups/`

Comment: many thanks for getting back to me.  i edited my post to include the output of the commands.  regarding /var/spool/cups/, i see log files in there (i have to sudo to see them) but they are not text files, they are full of control characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well.  i never found a fix for this.  i have established that printing works perfectly fine for everything except for the default PDF viewer.  to work around the problem i open the PDF in any other app, e.g. Chrome, and print it from there.

edit.  it fixed itself.  i had plugged the printer in to a USB hub.  when i plugged it directly into the laptop it downloaded another driver and after that it started working.